# How to UPDATE first occurrence WHERE certain condition is met?

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

The following statement works expect it's updating all of the occurrences which I understand.  I only want to update the first occurrence.  I tried using ROW_NUMBER() but can't seem to get a statement working that updates first occurrence based on a condition.

```
$sql = "UPDATE teams SET teamName = ?, userId = ? WHERE leagueId = ? AND userId = ?;";
```

[image]

Comment: I'm using prepared statements.  I later bind the params before executing.

Comment: Please tag your DBMS. It is DBMS-specific problem

Comment: You need to also show us the `ORDER BY` logic which determines what the "first" occurrence is here.

Comment: Using phpmyadmin.  Table is teams with columns are "teamId", "teamName", "userId", "leagueId".

one of my many attempts to use ROW_NUMBER()

`$sql = "UPDATE teams SET teamName = ?, userId = ? FROM (SELECT * ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY userId) WHERE leagueId = ? AND userId = ?) WHERE Rno=1;";`

Comment: Hi Shane, can you provide your table structure?

Comment: the userId will be "-1" if there's no user assigned to a team.  So I want to assign the first team with no user to the user.

Comment: `LIMIT 1` at the end of the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query for this purpose.

```
$sql = "UPDATE teams SET teamName = ?, userId = ? WHERE leagueId = ? AND userId = ? ORDER BY teamId ASC LIMIT 1;";
```

It will limit the result to only the first one with respect to ascending order of teamId column.

Comment: Thanks that worked perfect.  I appreciate everyone's help.